# Should I avoid casting to std::function when passing lambdas as parameters?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

If I have a function which is required to produce a hook from an input object, should I try to do that without casting to `std::function`? With these 2 options, which should I pick and is option 2 a meaningful improvement?

```
std::function<void()> CreateHook(std::function<void()> f)
{
    return []()
    {
        return Hook(f);
    };
}

// option 1:
void Hook(std::function<void()> f)
{
    // do something
}

// option 2:
<typename F>
void Hook(F f)
{
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Type erase only when you need to.  Either:

```
template<class F>
std::function<void()> CreateHook(F f) { return []() { return Hook(f); }; }
```

or even in C++1y:

```
template<class F>
auto CreateHook(F f) { return [f=std::move(f)]() { return Hook(f); }; }
```

but the second is probably overkill (the `f=std::move(f)` is not, but `auto` is, as I am guessing you will just store the return value in a `std::function` anyhow).

And if your `Hook` function is simple and stable:

```
template <typename F> void Hook(F f) {
  // do something
}
```

but if it is large and complex:

```
void Hook(std::function<void()> f) {
  // do something
}
```

because it lets you split interface from implementation.

The downside to this strategy is that some compilers suck at eliminating identical code in different functions causing binary size bloat, and it can cause some compile time bloat.

But if you defer type erasure in both cases, you can eliminate both two `virtual` function calls, and allow the compiler to inline the passed in `f` within the `Hook` body.

If however the interface for `CreateHook` cannot be changed, and `Hook` is only called from it, the `template` version of `Hook` is pointless, as it is only called with a `std::function` anyhow.

Answer (score 3):

In your example the template is pointless, because it is only ever instantiated for `T = std::function<void()>` - the template overload is chosen by *static* type of `f`, not the runtime type.